# Getting substring from string with powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to extract verssion number from MFC *.rc file. It looks like:

```
  VALUE "FileVersion", "1.22.333.4444\0"
```

actually I need two values - version 1.22.333.4444 and major version 1.22

I wrote the code below and it gives me the version, but it looks ugly

```
  $version = Get-Content -Path $rcPath | Select-String -Pattern 'FileVersion' -CaseSensitive –SimpleMatch -List | %{$_ -replace '[\\0]', ''} | %{$_ -replace '[^\d.]', ''}
```

So my questions are:

- Is there any simple way to obtain the version?
- How I can get the major version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a [Version] type you can use for that:

```
$text = 'VALUE "FileVersion", "1.22.333.4444\0"'
$version = [version]($text -replace '^.+?([0-9.]+)\\.+','$1')
$version


Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
1      22     333    4444
```

Then:

```
$version.ToString()

1.22.333.4444

'{0}.{1}' -f $version.major,$version.minor

1.22
```